# Can I optimize this SQL query that shows the users with 100+ entries in a day?

Tags: sql

So the table I'm working with has a setup like

| id | start_time |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 2021-04-13 00:58:31 |
| 5 | 2021-04-13 02:58:31 |
| 7 | 2021-04-13 03:52:31 |

etc. (there's also some other rows but those aren't relevant)

I want a query that will show all the users that have 100+ entries per day in between two dates.

Here's my query

```
SELECT id, CAST(start_time AS DATE) AS "Date", COUNT(CAST(start_time AS DATE)) AS "Amount" FROM events 
WHERE start_time BETWEEN '2020-05-01' AND '2020-05-31' GROUP BY id, CAST(start_time AS DATE)
HAVING COUNT(CAST(start_time AS DATE)) >=100;
```

It runs pretty slowly and I was wondering was there any better ways to optimize it. I've tried selecting just the Ids and that didn't seem to work well.

Comment: Maybe you can try creating a subquery or CTE with `start_time` already cast as `date`, to avoid doing that so many times (I'm not sure if SQL optimizes that). You didn't specify it, but you need not just the users, but the dates in which that happened, right? Otherwise you could get rid of a group by field.

Comment: I think I do need the dates, but if it is just the users, dropping that is a good idea. I've never used CTEs so I can look into that

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much you can do.  I would recommend logic as:

```
SELECT id, CAST(start_time AS DATE) AS "Date", COUNT(*) AS "Amount"
FROM events  e
WHERE start_time >= '2020-05-01' AND
      start_time < '2020-06-01'
GROUP BY id, CAST(start_time AS DATE)
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 100;
```

Note the change in the date comparisons.  Presumably, you want all of May, include May 31st.

Then for this query, you want an index on `events(start_time, id)`.  However, you would seem to have a large amount of data which will take time for the aggregation.